# Error - Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied in the dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, dynamic-queries

I am getting the error

> Procedure  has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

while executing the stored procedure shown below. If I am doing anything wrong, please help on this. I am spending more time on this now so just want to speed up. Thank you.

I would like to know if I am comparing the correct data type for the string data type variable 'CMFNUMBER' as ''0'' in the dynamic query below. I know if it is not dynamic then I will  compare like CMFNumber <> '0'. Just one quotation but for dynamic queries, is it CMFNumber <> ''0'', double quotation?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GET_Rates]
     @productIds VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
     @productStatusIds VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
     @pqrIds VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
     @origin VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
     @destination VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
     @contractId VARCHAR(12) = NULL,
     @originMode CHAR(1) = NULL,
     @destinationMode CHAR(1) = NULL,
     @oceanEquipmentCode VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
     @orderUserSort VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @queryOrderBy VARCHAR(MAX) = '[CUSTOMER_NAME]',
     @rowLimit INT = 0,
     @startRow INT = 0,
     @endRow INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @sWhere VARCHAR(MAX),
            @condition VARCHAR(MAX), 
            @condition1 VARCHAR(MAX), 
            @CTE NVARCHAR(MAX), 
            @sSELECT NVARCHAR(MAX), 
            @drop NVARCHAR(256)

    SET @sSQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT 
                     PQRP.PQR_ID,
                     PQRP.PRODUCT_ID,
                     P.PRODUCT_NAME,
                     P.PRODUCT_DSP_NAME,
                     PS.STATUS_DESCRIPTION
                 INTO 
                     ##PQRS
                 FROM
                     SCS_EPQR.DBO.PQR_PRODUCTS PQRP
                 JOIN 
                     SCS_EPQR.DBO.PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PQRP.PRODUCT_ID
                 JOIN 
                     SCS_EPQR.DBO.PRODUCT_STATUS PS ON PS.PRODUCT_STATUS = PQRP.PRODUCT_STATUS              WHERE 
                1=1
                AND PQRP.PRODUCT_ID IN (COALESCE((SELECT TXT_VALUE FROM DBO.FN_PARSETEXT2TABLE_TEXTONLY(@productIds, '','')), PQRP.PRODUCT_ID)) 
                AND PQRP.PRODUCT_STATUS IN (COALESCE((SELECT TXT_VALUE FROM DBO.FN_PARSETEXT2TABLE_TEXTONLY(@productStatusIds, '','')), PQRP.PRODUCT_STATUS)) 
                AND PQRP.PQR_ID IN (COALESCE((SELECT TXT_VALUE FROM DBO.FN_PARSETEXT2TABLE_TEXTONLY(@pqrIds, '','')), PQRP.PQR_ID)) ' 

    IF (@orderUserSort = 'TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES') 
        SET @Condition  = ', ISNULL(CPL.TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES, 0) AS TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILE'

    IF (@orderUserSort = 'TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES') 
        SET @Condition1  = 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT CMFNUMBER, COUNT(DISTINCT(CUSTOMERPROFILEID)) AS TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES
                    FROM
                        SCS_CUST_PROFILE.DBO.CUSTOMERPROFILELOCATIONS
                    WHERE
                        CMFNUMBER <> ''0'' 
                        AND CMFNUMBER IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY CMFNUMBER, CUSTOMERPROFILEID
                ) CPL
                    ON CAST(CPL.CMFNUMBER AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(50))'

    SET @CTE = ';WITH CTE_RATE_TLI AS(
            SELECT DISTINCT TLIREFERENCENUMBER
            FROM SCS_EPQR.DBO.OCEAN_SHIPPING_DETAIL_NETWORK_COST
            WHERE 1=1 
                AND ORIGIN_CODE = COALESCE(@origin, ORIGIN_CODE) 
                AND DEST_CODE = COALESCE(@destination, DEST_CODE) 
                AND CONTRACT_ID = COALESCE(@contractId, CONTRACT_ID) 
                AND ORIGIN_MODE = COALESCE(@originMode, ORIGIN_MODE) 
                AND DEST_MODE = COALESCE(@destinationMode, DEST_MODE) 
                AND OCEAN_EQUIPMENT_CODE = COALESCE(@oceanEquipmentCode, OCEAN_EQUIPMENT_CODE) 
        ),
        CTE_COM AS (
            SELECT RT.TLIREFERENCENUMBER, COM.COMMODITY_DESCRIPTION
            FROM 
                CTE_RATE_TLI RT
                JOIN FMC_TLI_RW TLI
                    ON TLI.TLIREFERENCENUMBER = RT.TLIREFERENCENUMBER
                JOIN FMC_COMMODITY_RW COM
                    ON COM.COMMODITY_NUMBER = TLI.COMMODITY_NUMBER
            GROUP BY
                RT.TLIREFERENCENUMBER, COM.COMMODITY_DESCRIPTION
        )

        SELECT * 
        INTO ##TEMPDATA
        FROM (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @queryOrderBy) AS ROWNUM,
                C.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                CP.CUSTOMERNAME C_CUSTOMER_NAME,
                C.CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
                C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
                PQR.QUOTE_NUM,
                NC.*, 
                COM.COMMODITY_DESCRIPTION TLI_COMMODITY_DESCRIPTION,
                PQRS.PRODUCT_NAME,
                PQRS.PRODUCT_DSP_NAME,
                PQRS.STATUS_DESCRIPTION PRODUCT_STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
                EQUIP.OCEAN_EQUIPMENT_NAME,
                DP.ORIGIN_LOCATION_NAME, 
                DP.DEST_LOCATION_NAME,
                DP.COMMODITY_NAME,
                NC_EXP_DATE = COALESCE(NC.MOD_EXPIRE_ON, NC.EXPIRE_ON),
                NC_DEST_COUNTRY_CODE_HBL = LEFT( DP.DEST_CODE,2),
                ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME = OCOUNTRY.COUNTRY_NAME,
                DEST_COUNTRY_NAME = DCOUNTRY.COUNTRY_NAME,
                NC_DEST_POSTAL= DP.DEST_POSTAL,
                NC_ORIGIN_POSTAL = DP.ORIGIN_POSTAL,
                TERMS_OF_SALE = DP.TERMS_OF_SALE,

                NC_ORIGIN_COUNTRY_CODE_HBL = LEFT( DP.ORIGIN_CODE,2)
                ' + @condition + '

            FROM 
                SCS_EPQR.DBO.OCEAN_SHIPPING_DETAIL_NETWORK_COST NC
                JOIN ##PQRS PQRS
                    ON PQRS.PQR_ID = NC.PQR_ID 
                JOIN SCS_EPQR.DBO.PQR
                    ON PQRS.PQR_ID = PQR.PQR_ID
                LEFT JOIN SCS_EPQR.DBO.OCEAN_SHIPPING_DETAIL_PARAMS DP
                    ON DP.OSDP_ID = NC.OSDP_ID
                LEFT JOIN SCS_EPQR.DBO.COMPANY C
                    ON C.PQR_ID = NC.PQR_ID
                LEFT JOIN WEBPM.DBO.BUS_OCEAN_EQUIPMENT EQUIP
                    ON EQUIP.OCEAN_EQUIPMENT_CODE = NC.OCEAN_EQUIPMENT_CODE
                LEFT JOIN WEBPM.DBO.BUS_COUNTRY OCOUNTRY
                        ON DP.ORIGIN_COUNTRY_CODE = OCOUNTRY.COUNTRY_CODE       
                LEFT JOIN WEBPM.DBO.BUS_COUNTRY DCOUNTRY
                        ON DP.DEST_COUNTRY_CODE = DCOUNTRY.COUNTRY_CODE                                                 
                LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERPROFILES CP
                ON PQR.CP_ID = CP.CUSTOMERPROFILEID 
                LEFT JOIN CTE_COM COM
                    ON COM.TLIREFERENCENUMBER = NC.TLIREFERENCENUMBER
                ' + @Condition1 + '
            WHERE
                1=1
                AND NC.ORIGIN_CODE = COALESCE(@origin, NC.ORIGIN_CODE) 
                AND NC.DEST_CODE = COALESCE(@destination, NC.DEST_CODE) 
                AND NC.CONTRACT_ID = COALESCE(@contractId, NC.CONTRACT_ID) 
                AND NC.ORIGIN_MODE = COALESCE(@originMode, NC.ORIGIN_MODE) 
                AND NC.DEST_MODE = COALESCE(@destinationMode, NC.DEST_MODE) 
                AND NC.OCEAN_EQUIPMENT_CODE = COALESCE(@oceanEquipmentCode, NC.OCEAN_EQUIPMENT_CODE) 
        )X
        WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN  
        CASE WHEN (@rowLimit > 0) THEN @startRow ELSE ROWNUM END
        AND CASE WHEN (@rowLimit > 0) THEN @endRow ELSE ROWNUM END'

IF (@orderUserSort <> 'TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES') 
    SET @sSELECT = 'SELECT ##TEMPDATA.*, ISNULL(CPL.TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES, 0) TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES FROM ##TEMPDATA
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT CMFNUMBER, COUNT(DISTINCT(CUSTOMERPROFILEID)) AS TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES
                    FROM
                        SCS_CUST_PROFILE.DBO.CUSTOMERPROFILELOCATIONS
                    WHERE
                        CMFNUMBER <> ''0''
                        AND CMFNUMBER IS NOT NULL
                        AND CMFNUMBER IN (SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER FROM ##TEMPDATA WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER <> ''0'')
                    GROUP BY CMFNUMBER, CUSTOMERPROFILEID
                ) CPL
            ON CAST(CPL.CMFNUMBER AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(##TEMPDATA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS VARCHAR(50))'
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @sSELECT = 'SELECT * FROM ##TEMPDATA'
END

SET @drop = 'DROP TABLE ##PQRS, ##TEMPDATA'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sSQL, @CTE, @sSELECT, @drop,  N'@productIds VARCHAR(max), @productStatusIds VARCHAR(max), @pqrIds VARCHAR(max), @origin VARCHAR(10), @destination VARCHAR(10),
                           @contractId VARCHAR(12), @originMode CHAR(1), @destinationMode CHAR(1), @oceanEquipmentCode VARCHAR(10), @orderUserSort VARCHAR(100), @queryOrderBy VARCHAR(max),
                           @rowLimit INT, @startRow INT, @endRow INT', @productIds, @productStatusIds, @pqrIds, @origin, @destination, @contractId, @originMode, @destinationMode, @oceanEquipmentCode,
                           @orderUserSort, @queryOrderBy, @rowLimit, @startRow, @endRow ;


SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: OH DEAR!!!! This is wide open to sql injection. The reason for your error is because you built up a string and then pass parameters to it. This whole procedure needs a complete rebuild. Instead of passing delimited lists you should look into passing table valued parameters. And to be totally honest I am 99.9999999% this could be done without any dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange - would you please let me know how it is vulnerable to sql injection because I am passing all the variables coming from UI to be passed as a parameter and have not concatenated anywhere. In addition using this sp_executesql

Comment: Ok I fixed for the above error as per @SeanLange by updating as SET sSQL = sSQL + CTE + sSELECT

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL sSQL

Comment: OK perhaps you didn't concatenate with user input. But your dynamic sql is all over the place. The performance here is a timebomb and nothing I would want to maintain. It seems way overly complicated, to the point I can't even unravel what this is doing.

Comment: Solved. I was missing to assign the space to this variables condition VARCHAR(MAX) = '', condition1 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

Comment: I still think you could do this a lot cleaner without all that crazy dynamic sql. But glad you got it working.

Comment: @SeanLange anyway thank you! I will. :)